# How to solve optimization problem involving fixed order of sites to be visited at given time windows

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I hope someone can give a suggestion, that is only that I am asking for.

So there is an array of sites that should be visited in a given order (a run). Each site has to be visited in a given time window constraint and job there is to be done in a particular duration. There is also a traveling time to that site from a previous site given. This is a rough illustration of one example run:

[image]

The final goal is to minimize the overall time needed to visit all sites and finish all jobs.

First question: is there anything, any algorithm that solves closely similar to this problem?

Second: In your opinion, what is the best approach for solving this?

Comment: So what would be the minimum time for this sample case? Looks like a round robin scheduling for me.

Comment: No, I don't have solution for this example, but it is a good representation of the problem. I was thinking to create a loop and then start by solving the smallest window possible, by solving that I will break all other overlapped windows and thus make them as candidates to solve in next iteration and so on.

Comment: But you also have to visit other sites simultaneously? My initial idea of round robin seems incorrect as it would actually abort a process for certain period of time. How are you going to visit them if there are overlapping intervals? Also, if there isn't a correct answer for this one, then it's hard to say if we are on the right track.

Comment: Overlapped are only constrains, like a site works only 1 hour, but the actual job is less then that (like 15 mins or so),   so if we decide to finish the job in the site no 4 (that can take up to 15 mins) we then can split/break all overlapped windows and process them in a next iteration, your thoughts?